# SharePoint security programming issue

Tags: c#, security, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I have deployed a publishing portal. I am developing a ASP.Net web application using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ASP.Net + SharePoint Server 2007 SDK.

I found sometimes we need to use SPWebApplication.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = false in order to walk around, e.g. using SharePoint API to create a site in a site collection. I want to know why we need to execute SPWebApplication.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = false? What is the reason behind the scene?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the user that is executing the commands have permissions to run the commands?  Based on [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spformdigestsettings_properties.aspx), it appears that you are disabling security validation when you set that property to false.

A better way to get "super user" permissions to execute a command that the current user doesn't have permissions to run is to use `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() 
{
    // Note: It's important that you create all new SPSite and SPWeb
    // objects in the elevated context in order to actually use elevated
    // privileges. Failure to do so will cause your code to execute
    // without elevated privileges.
    using(SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
    {
        using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
        {
             // run code here that requires elevated privileges.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: So, 1. SPWebApplication.FormDigestSettings.Enabled is used to disable user permission checking? 2. Using impersonation could achieve the same goal? 3. End user is accessing from web, and IIS is using user identity account of worker process to execute, I am wondering for user permission checking using SPWebApplication.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = true, does SharePoint check permission against IIS worker process identity or some other identity?

Comment: 1. It appears that is the case, yes.  2. using this method of impersonation causes the code to be run as the "System Account", with all permissions associated with it.  This account is usually the service account configured in IIS.  3. Sharepoint uses the currently logged in user's identity to execute code, and if the current user doesn't have permissions, then you get access denied errors.

Comment: So for 3, it means if user who is SharePoint web application administrator, who has permission to create a sub-site, there is no need to use the code block you provided? And for a normal user, we need such code?

Comment: There is a better, more stable way to execute command with system permissions as mentioned here: http://solutionizing.net/2009/01/06/elegant-spsite-elevation/

More stable, as it will not swap thread identity. I had issues with RunWithElevatedPrivileges in some places and just using SPSite constructor, providing system account user token, resolved it.
Reasons can be seen here: http://soumya-sharepointblog.blogspot.com/2008/07/sharepoint-elevated-privilege-without.html